# Using either Trim or Replace in PowerShell to clean up anything not contained in quotation marks

Tags: powershell, replace, trim

I'm trying to write a script that that will remove everything except text contained in quotation marks from a result-set generated by a SQL query. Not sure whether trim or -replace will do this.

Here is a sampling of the result-set:

> a:5:{s:3:"Client Service";a:4:{s:15:"Client Training";b:0;s:11:"Payer
>   Error";

I would like it to end up looking like this:

```
Client Service
Client Training
Payer Error
```

I've tried everything I know to do in my limited PowerShell and RegEx familiarity and still haven't been able to figure out a good solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version that uses Regex to capture the strings including their quotes in to an array and then removes the quote marks with `-replace`:

```
$text = 'a:5:{s:3:"Client Service";a:4:{s:15:"Client Training";b:0;s:11:"Payer Error";'

([regex]::matches($Text, '(")(.*?)(")')).value -replace '"'
```

There's without a doubt a regex to get the strings without their quotes in the first place but i'm a bit of a regex novice.

Comment: That's great! Thank you for your help on that. Works like a charm!

Comment: @esat7 no worries, be great if you could upvote also :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$s = 'a:5:{s:3:"Client Service";a:4:{s:15:"Client Training";b:0;s:11:"Payer Error";'
```

Replace the start of string up to the first quote, or the last quote up to the end of string. Then what you're left with is:

```
   Client Service";a:4:{s:15:"Client Training";b:0;s:11:"Payer Error
```

Now the bits you don't want are "in quotation marks" and that's easy to match with `".*?"` so replace that with a space.

Overall, two replaces:

```
$s -replace '^[^"]*"|"[^"]*$' -replace '".*?"', ' '

Client Service Client Training Payer Error
```

Comment: Thank you for providing that. Really useful!